# Problem with nicematrix and footnotes

Tags: nicematrix

I formerly used `\usepackage[footnote]{nicematrix}`, but this doesn't work any more, after changing my computer and updating MiKTeX.

The error is

```
! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \IfClassLoadeTF {beamer}{\bool_set_false:N\c_nicematrix_footnot...I.8442}
```

I want to have the note at the foot of the page. When I write `\usepackage{nicematrix}`, without `[footnote]`, no footnote appears. What can I do to fix this?

My code is

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[footnote]{nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\ttfamily
\begin{NiceTabular}{lc@{\hphantom{-}}c@{\hphantom{-}}cc}
Tact\footnote{voilà} & 8    & 9    & 10    & 11     \\
Sup-    &      &      &       & quelle \\
Cont-   & quel & \Block[l]{}{\llap{-}le}   \\
Ten-    &      &      & quelle \\
Bas-    &      & quel & \Block[l]{}{\llap{-}le} \\
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (3-2.south east) 
        -- (3-2.south west)
        -- (5-3.south west) 
        -- (5-3.south east) 
        -- (4-4.south east) 
        -- (4-4.south west) ;
  \draw (4-4.south east) -- (2-5.south east) -- (2-5.south west) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug. It will be corrected in the next version of `nicematrix`.

As a workaround, you can use `footnotehyper` instead of `footnote`:

```
\usepackage[footnotehyper]{nicematrix}
```